# Embedded Tomcat without WEB-INF

Tags: tomcat

I am struggling to setup an embedded Tomcat server. The setup I have is not similar to the Tomcat convention, as I have a somePath/www directory, where my static files including index.html are. I also don't have WEB-INF and I don't have web.xml.

I need Tomcat to open index.html when requesting localhost:8080/. This does not work and I get a page being not found error. Nevertheless when I request localhost:8080/index.html the request returns the relevant file. My current current attempted configuration is shown below.

```
tomcat.addWebapp("/", "somePath/www");
Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/", "somePath/www");
Wrapper defaultServlet = ctx.createWrapper();
defaultServlet.setName("default");
defaultServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
defaultServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0");
defaultServlet.addInitParameter("listings", "false");
defaultServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
ctx.addChild(defaultServlet);
ctx.addServletMapping("/*", "default");
```

On the other hand, for the following setup:

```
tomcat.addWebapp("/MY_APP", "somePath/www");
```

localhost:8080/MY_APP/ works fine too.

Is there a way to have embedded Tomcat load index.html located in an arbitrary directory, when the url is just the context root? I also require the solution to not change the directory structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for tomcat to serve `index.html` on requests with just the context path (`http://localhost:8080/`) you need to apply the following modifications:

- Add `"index.html"` to the list of welcome files of your context using `Context.addWelcomeFile()`. The file will be looked up relative to your context's base directory. You can also use relative paths, eg. `"static/index.html"`
- Use `"/"` pattern in servlet mapping for `"default"` servlet. Only then tomcat will consider welcome files and rewrite the request path before calling default servlet.

After applying these changes the code should look like this:

```
Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/", "somePath/www");

defaultServlet = ctx.createWrapper();
defaultServlet.setName("default");
defaultServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
defaultServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0");
defaultServlet.addInitParameter("listings", "false");
defaultServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

ctx.addChild(defaultServlet);
ctx.addServletMapping("/", "default");
ctx.addWelcomeFile("index.html");
```

This is similar to how tomcat configures the context when you call `tomcat.addWebapp()`, so you could just use this:

```
Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("/", "somePath/www");
```

Comment: I'm just starting to work with this. Note that the context path should be `""`, not `"/"`. And there no longer seems to be a context `addServletMapping()` in Tomcat 9; use `ctx.addServletMappingDecoded()`. And (here's the trickiest of all), you now have to add `tomcat.getConnector()` to create a default connector; otherwise Tomcat mysteriously won't work at all; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011424/421049 .