# Java Web Application using Embedded Tomcat Is Running but not Showing in Browser

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, heroku

I followed the steps on the page linked below to try and make an incredibly simple java web app using the embedded tomcat servlet.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyYfV.png) is what I get in the shell after running webapp.

The server runs but then it doesnt show anything in the web browser. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyBth.png) from the browser.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxs5Z.png) is a screenshot of my folder structure after packaging it with maven.

**pom/xml file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.heroku.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>embeddedTomcatSample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>embeddedTomcatSample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.16</tomcat.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>embeddedTomcatSample</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Launcher class:**

```
package launch;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.catalina.WebResourceRoot;
import org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet;
import org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        //The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        //Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }

        tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        StandardContext ctx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

        // Declare an alternative location for your "WEB-INF/classes" dir
        // Servlet 3.0 annotation will work
        File additionWebInfClasses = new File("target/classes");
        WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(ctx);
        resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes",
                additionWebInfClasses.getAbsolutePath(), "/"));
        ctx.setResources(resources);

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }
}
```

**Servlet class:**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
        name = "MyServlet",
        urlPatterns = {"/hello"}
    )
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        out.write("hello heroku".getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

}
```

I have tried this on Linux and Windows. I have also followed 2 other similar simple guides and got the same problem.

Can anyone please help me find where the issue is? Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't show text output as screen captures. [Edit] the question and show your [mcve] and show the errors or traces as copyable, searchable text. Screenshots are rarely useful when discussing server-side code like this.

Comment: We need to see some code. Edit and add the POM file you're using, plus the main class.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, sorry I am new to this. I have added the pom and java code - it is the same as the code given on the heroku guide. Unfortunately this is to be the minimal working example...

Comment: Have you tried visiting `http://localhost:8080/hello`?

Answer (score 3):

hopefully my answer comes late, but I had apparently the same problem last night. I found the answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998387/code-works-with-embedded-apache-tomcat-8-but-not-with-9-whats-changed):

> It looks like you haven't added a Connector to your embedded server.

This was not necessary with tomcat 8, and therefore most of the sample code available doesn't mention this. Solution given worked for me. Just add the following line after the `tomcat.setPort` call:

```
tomcat.getConnector(); // Trigger the creation of the default connector
```